# TCL get array value using variable as key name

Tags: tcl

I have the following array list that contains IANA Cipher Suites IDs (Key Name) with their corresponding names (Values)

```
array set IANA_Ciphers [list {0000} {"TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL"} \
        {0001} {"TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5"} \
        {0002} {"TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA"} \
        {0003} {"TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5"} \
        [...]
        {C0AF} {"TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8"} ]
```

Now I need to be able to access this array's values dynamically but when i use the following code i get the error "**can't read "IANA_Ciphers(0000)": no such element in array**"

```
set ciphers "000000010002"
set tmp [string range $ciphers 0 3] ;# which gives "0000"
puts $IANA_Ciphers($tmp) ;# throws the error
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: I tried your example and it works.

Comment: If you have Tcl 8.5 or 8.6, you might be better off using `dict get` instead of writing the values into an array.

Comment: Thanks Donal, unfortunately I do not and the dict procedure is not yet supported on my box, but that's a great idea and I will implement it after the upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the variable as

```
set ciphers "000000010002"
```

**Update 2**

I don't know whether your additional braces in the `array set` command is a typo or not.

```
array set IANA_Ciphers [list {0000} {"TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL"} \
        {0001} {"TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5"} \
        {0002} {"TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA"} \
        {0003} {"TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5"} \
        [...]
        {C0AF} {"TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8"} ]
} # This '}' is not needed at all.
```

You should be getting error as

```
--------
invalid command name "}"
    while executing
"}"
```

By the way, without that, I have tried your code and it is working fine for me.

```
array set IANA_Ciphers [list {0000} {"TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL"} \
        {0001} {"TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5"} \
        {0002} {"TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA"} \
        {0003} {"TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5"} \
        {C0AF} {"TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8"} ]

set ciphers "000000010002"
set tmp [string range $ciphers 0 3] ;# which gives "0000"
puts "Key : $tmp"
puts "Value : $IANA_Ciphers($tmp)"
```

**Output :**

```
Key : 0000
Value : "TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL"
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo when I wrote the example, the dollar is not present in the original code. thanks

Comment: Sorry again, the '}' also was not part of the example and I have reflected this in my question. I am running this code on a BigIP device and the fact that you can successfully display the array element tells me the issue must be coming from the F5's TCL implementation on this box.

Comment: @ Tacu : I have posted your modified code with proper output above. It is working fine. May be you are missing some other input to share. Post your code with output. Also, share the `parray IANA_Ciphers` command output.

Comment: @ Dinesh : Thanks ! I have found a solution and you're right the code was good: I have realized that i had forgotten to convert the $ciphers variable, that I obtain from a binary scan of the TCP payload, to upper case, so when a client sent a list of cipher suites that contained at least a letter, the system started throwing the error. I am marking your answer as the solution.